# Why isn't a ViewModel object destroyed when I rotate a screen?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I have read [The lifecycle of a ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle).

I create a activity and associate a viewModel to the activity lifecycle, the lifecycle of viewModel is equal to the lifecycle of the activity.

1: When I finish the activity, the `onDestroy()` of the activity will be fired, and the `onCleared()` of the viewModel will be fired, then the viewModel will be destroyed. It run just like this.

2: If I rotate a screen of the activity, the activity will be destroyed first, then it will be recreate again.
So the `onDestroy()` of the activity will be fired when I rotate the screen, and the lifecycle of the activity will finish, so I think the lifecycle of the viewModel will finish too, and the `onCleared()` of the viewModel will be fired, then the viewModel will be destroyed, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ViewModel is destroyed only when the activity is finishing (due to the user completely dismissing the activity or due to finish() being called on the activity).

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that  rotation screen is  only temporarily destroying the activity and it will not destroy ViewModel object?

Comment: Yes, onDestroy for the activity will be called as System is destroying the activity temporarily. ViewModel will be preserved.

Answer (score 4):

ViewModelStoreOwner:  A ViewModelStoreOwner is merely an interface. Any class that implements the getViewModelStore() defined by this interface becomes the owner of ViewModelStore.

Both Fragment and Activity implements ViewModelStoreOwner. These classes maintain a viewModelStore and value is restored appropriately.

A ViewModelStore can be considered as a container that stores the ViewModels in a HashMap. Where the key is string value and value is the ViewModel being saved(ViewModelProvider uses a concatenation of the string_key + ViewModel class canonical name).

How does ViewModel survive configuration changes:
Every Activity and fragment has a ViewModelStore, which makes them a ViewModelStoreOwner.
Whenever an activity is first started, the getViewModelStore() method is called and a ViewModelStore instance is created if it is null.
A CustomViewModelFactory is used for creating a ViewModel because Android will give you a new instance if it's not yet created for that particular ViewModelStoreOwner
The ViewModel is then stored into ViewModelStore.

If you go ahead and rotate the screen, onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() is called and viewModelStore instance is saved into NonConfigurationInstance for use after configuration changes.

When the app finishes rotating, getViewModelStore() method is called and an old instance of ViewModelStore is provided to the activity from the NonConfigurationInstance object.
This is how ViewModel survives configuration changes.

The Lifecycle Events are observed and in case of onDestroy event if configuration is not changing(device is not rotating and app is being shutdown), viewModel store is cleared.

Comment: Perfect, it took me a long time to find all this information on my own, while it has been summarized here in a single post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @alpha-1 answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66634305/592217

*Instead of putting logic in your Activity to determine why it is being destroyed you should use a ViewModel object to contain the relevant view data for your Activity. If the Activity is going to be recreated due to a configuration change the ViewModel does not have to do anything since it will be preserved and given to the next Activity instance. If the Activity is not going to be recreated then the ViewModel will have the onCleared() method called where it can clean up any data it needs to before being destroyed.*

*You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.*

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy

[image]